# Google App Engine - Datastore key ID int vs string perfomance

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Hello i was wondering how big is performance difference  between using Int and String ID for Entity Key.

I was unable to found any article about this.  In my opinion 
in big scale comparing long strings must be much slower comparing int64s or maybe I am wrong  and there is some cool algorithm that make it run at same speed.

I want to use  sha256 hash as string ID, but don't wanna lose anything compared to int ID.

For example if I have 1 000 000 000 entities of same kind and I am using sha512 has string ID (128 chars )for entities, will be read (getting from datastore)  of 1 entity slower than  using int64 ID at same amount of entities ? IF yes than how much ?

Thanks for any answer or suggestion, Hope I explained it right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. I don't think there would be any difference. App Engine stores trillions of entities, and I am sure they have enough computer science PhDs on their team to optimize such a basic task as retrieving a single record.
2. Even if there is a difference, it would be negligible. I can't think of a use case, where it would matter.
3. There are many more decisions that have a much bigger impact on performance.
4. I think you should focus on getting millions of users first. Once you get there, you can raise a lot of money, and then you can optimize your application.

Comment: I don't think it was meant to be unfriendly, the point is don't lose your time over optimizing for problems you have yet to encounter.

Comment: Sorry, I did not want it to sound unfriendly. I myself wasted a lot of time optimizing something that later proved to be unnecessary.

Comment: To be fair, "if there had been a perf difference", then it would have been a very good idea to choose the fast one early in the development. Converting later can be very difficult (I have to deal with the conversion issue in real projects).

Comment: "The First Rule of Program Optimization: Don't do it. The Second Rule of Program Optimization (for experts only!): Don't do it yet."